# Unable to enable jquery UI module in drupal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal

I have been trying to enable jquery UI module and have been unable to to do. I realised that the documentation is crappy but even following the community from 
http://drupal.org/node/434424
doesnot seem to work. Any pointers???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried to enable the dependencies first..This was the error..Now got it working :)

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. That was exactly what was happening to me and I'm so glad that there was someone on this internet who was willing to document how they solved the issue. Thanks again. +1

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but later realized that apart from extracting the files in the sites/all/modules folder, one needs to extract the jquery.ui zip file from the google code site and extract the folder to sites/all/libraries and rename it to jquery.ui

More in the readme.txt